# Round up Y axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

When you plot a bar chart in ggplot2, the y axis labelling automatically stops at the break below the highest value.
In the graph the last label is 40, whereas I want it to round up to the next break which would be 50.

```
 set.seed (52)
 date<-data.frame(date=sample(seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), as.Date('2020-01-31'), by="day"),1000,replace=TRUE))
 ggplot(data=date)+
 geom_bar(mapping=aes(x=date))
```

[image]

I know adding +scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,50)) will manually make the graph at 50 but I would need to keep changing this bit of the code. Is there a way to do this dynamically within the ggplot function?

Comment: Try adding `scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(15))` in the final part of your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option could be defining a sequence function for breaks like this:

```
#Function
f <- function(y) seq(floor(min(y)), ceiling(max(y)),by=10)
#Code
set.seed (52)
date<-data.frame(date=sample(seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), as.Date('2020-01-31'), by="day"),1000,replace=TRUE))
ggplot(data=date)+
  geom_bar(mapping=aes(x=date))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = f)
```

Output:

[image]

Another option could be playing with the max values from your variable and use the function `round_any()` from `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
#Code
set.seed (52)
date<-data.frame(date=sample(seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), as.Date('2020-01-31'), by="day"),1000,replace=TRUE))
#Extract limits
upper <- round_any(max(table(date$date)),10,f=ceiling)
#Plot
ggplot(data=date)+
  geom_bar(mapping=aes(x=date))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,upper))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Can this be done with the numbers rounded up to the nearest 10?

Comment: @Basil I have added an update for your issue, I hope that can be useful!!!